# Rxjs to hold current member

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have inherited a code base that uses a Behavioursubject to hold the current member. When retrieving the currently selected member, a private variable this._member is returned.

I would change the code so that you subscribe to currentMember in the component.

I am wondering if there is any reason this approach is used, as opposed to my suggested solution?

```
export class MemberService {
  ...
  private _member: Member;
  private _memberSource = new BehaviourSubject<Member>(this._member);
  // public currentMember = this._memberSource.asObservable(); // My solution

  setSelectedMember(currMem: Member): void {
    this._member = currMem;
    this._memberSource.next(this._member);
  }

  getSelectedMember(): Member {
    return this._member;
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having `this._member` as an addition property is bad code. It is completely unnecessary because the BehaviourSubject already holds the value. The `getSelectedMember` function might as well return `this._memberSource.getValue()`

imo the best solution is just to make the behaviour subject public. it already has a set, get and subscribe function. no reason to wrap them in getters and setters. Make it readonly to prevent changing the subject itself

```
export class MemberService {
...
   public readonly member = new BehaviourSubject<Member>(null);
...
}
```

you can now:

```
memberService.member.subscribe(...); // subscribe
const currentMember = memberService.member.getValue(); // get the value
memberService.member.next(new Member()); // set the value
```

its way easier to maintain and a lot less code

Answer (score 0):

No, your solution is idiomatic to Angular actually. Getting things out of a service imperatively (with the getter) has its uses, but in Angular most of the times we can do without that.